# AMAZON EC2 Micro instances have different IP addresses?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I was wondering if working with 1000 Micro-instances -> sending a request per second through every instance goes through a different IP Address?

If not, can anyone point me out in the right direction so i could achieve the same?

My use-case ideally requires forwarding a request through a different IP Address

Comment: Each EC2 instance (if you choose it) gets a public different IP address

Comment: @Michelem Can 1000 micro-instances be configured with 1000 different public ip addresses and would these be dynamic as well (change after 24hrs or so)

Comment: They are static until you stop and restart the instances. You can also buy permanent IP (called EIP, Elastic IP). But Amazon won't let you start 1000 instances before you make a specific request to them, initially your account can run, if I remember well, maximum 25 instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not recommend this approach.

- You would need to increase your EC2 Limits to be able to launch this many instances
- There is no guarantee that this many micro instances would be available at the desired time
- It would be a massive undertaking to coordinate all the instances to do your bidding (eg starting, stopping, configuring).
- It would cost .02 * 1000 = $20 per hour (not bad, actually) -- possibly less for Spot Instances but you might not get that many at Spot pricing

I assume your goal is to do performance testing from a range of different IP addresses? You could use [Bees with Machine Guns](http://blog.apps.chicagotribune.com/2010/07/08/bees-with-machine-guns/) to control the servers.

If possible, I would recommend doing performance testing from a smaller number of instances with fewer IP addresses. If necessary, change the limitation in your system that requires so many different IP addresses.