# Does an AMAZON EC2 Micro-Instance change IP for every reboot?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Let's say I have a micro-instance and i reboot it 100 times a day,

Would that give me a new external ip address each time? and is there a limit to the number of times i can be assigned an IP Address/reboot?

Comment: Related to: [AMAZON EC2 Micro instances have different IP addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32410552/amazon-ec2-micro-instances-have-different-ip-addresses/32412337#32412337)

Answer (score 3):

A reboot of an Amazon EC2 instance ***will not*** change its public IP address. The virtual machine keeps running, only the operating system restarts.

If the instance has an IP address allocated via the **Auto-assign Public IP** setting, then stopping the instance and then starting it again ***might*** allocate a new Public IP address. Note that this will also restart the hourly billing charge.

If the instance has an **Elastic IP Address**, then the IP address ***will not*** change until the Elastic IP Address is specifically removed or assigned to another instance.

Comment: What would be your method/suggestion to change the Public IP Address of the micro-instance with minimal server downtime

Comment: @wolfgang If you associate an Elastic IP with the instance then the instance loses its auto-assigned public IP. If you then disassociate the Elastic IP then the instance is automatically assigned a new public IP. No guarantee that it will be a different public IP to the earlier one but I'm guessing it will likely be different. Any particular reason that you want a new public IP every 15 minutes?

Comment: @jarmod Performance testing